# Set cluster name of elasticsearch with environmental variable

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

I am running **elasticsearch** service with **docker-compose**. I need to specify custom cluster name. 
As I found in this [github ticket](https://github.com/docker-library/elasticsearch/issues/68#issuecomment-191294944), I can pass a custom cluster name in **es.cluster.name** property. This approach is working for me.

### Question:

**Is possible to set cluster name with env variables, even with version 2.4 and this docker image [Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/)?**

In docker [documentation for 5.3 version](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-prod-cluster-composefile), I see I could also specify it in environmental variables but in elasticsearch:2.4 this is not working. I have to use version 2.4 because of spring data compatibility.

I didn't manage to get to end of this with version 2.4, or was this enabled only in latest versions?

Part of docker compose file:

```
elastic:
    image: "elasticsearch:2.4-alpine"
    # Setting property value works
    command: "elasticsearch -Des.cluster.name=custom-cluster-name" 

    # Setting env properties is not working, but I would prefer it this way
    #environment: 
    # - es.cluster.name=custom-cluster-name
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I think the problem is with dots in the environment variable. Bash throws an error if there is a dot in the variable name

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (I was on ES 1.5.2):

```
    command: elasticsearch -Des.cluster.name=<cluster_name>
```